# How can i map HttpResponseError value through HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using **Angular** with **nodejs**, in **nodejs**; I'm wrapping errors in custom format, like:

**server/routes/data.route.js:**

```
router.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    getData().then(data => res.send(data))
            .catch(errObj => res.status(errObj .status).send(errObj ));  
});
```

this errObj and each error value that I return from **nodejs** will be in this format:

```
{
    title: 'cannot update document',
    control: 'name', 
    status: 406,
    desc: 'new doc is invalid name'
}
```

So, in each error callback inside `subscribe` in **Angular**; I expect errObj inside `HttpErrorResponse`, like:

**src/app/app.component.ts**

```
this.service.create(document).subscribe(
    res => { ... },
    error => {
        // I have to rewrite this in each error callback
        let errObj = error.error;
        // do something
    }
)
```

So, I thought to use `map` of `rxjs/operators` to map error directly from `HttpInterceptor`, like:

```
 // inside intercept function
return next.handle(req.clone()).pipe(
    map(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return (res instanceof HttpErrorResponse)? res.error: res;
    })
);
```

Each time i log res inside map, it prints: `{type: 0}`, and obviously it doesn't work.

How can i map response from `HttpInterceptor`?

Comment: If you look at the response http status, is it a bad request response?

Comment: @YoussefTounoussi i know, i wanna catch it inside error callback!

Comment: No just asking, are you sure that nodeJs is returning a bad request HTTP status ?

Comment: Yes, cause i use tap function and it prints error as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a error interceptor,  example :

**error.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 406) {
                // do something

            }
            const error = err.error || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: @nimeresam did you  check it ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try this, and update me with the logs

```
return next.handle(req.clone()).pipe(
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
                        tap(res=> {
                            if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
                                    console.log('We have response'); // Please look at this first   
                                   console.log(res); // Please look at this first                                   
                            }
                        }),
                        catchError((err: any) => {
                               console.log('We have an error here')
                             return (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)?   err.error: of(err);
                        }));

                  }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the error in the interceptor and return observable with the transformed value.

The way you are doing it, you just map and propagate the error to the next handler.